# Integrated RC Filter Chip

Tags: filter, microchip

I need an 100 tımes RC Low pass filter(6MhZ) for an application. There lots of another component in my layout. Do you know any RC low pass filter 'array' or similar chip ?

update : I have 100 Ouptuts and I should filter all of them with a basic rc filter.

Comment: Do you actually mean 100 instances of a low-pass filter?

Comment: I have 100 Ouptuts and I should filter all of them with a basic rc filter.

Comment: Well, buy 100 resistors and 100 capacitors. There's no way a chip integrates the caps anyway, you can find some chips with 8 to some 10s of resistors though, but they usually have a common terminal, which is no good in a RCLP.

Comment: We do engineering here, not handwaving. I don't know what a "100 times RC low pas filter" is.  100x *what*?  Attenuation as some frequency? Closing this mess.

Comment: You can buy resistor arrays, and capacitor arrays and put them together.  That might save some on the pieces count.

Comment: There are many filtering devices intended for EMI reduction type applications.  Some do come as arrays, sometimes quite tiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the load on the output of the RC low pass filter, the "R" value could range from a few ohms to several hundred ohms but for a 6MHz cut-off frequency, the product of RC will always equal below: -

\$\dfrac{1}{2\pi f_c}\$ = 2.65E-8

If your load is 100kohms then choosing R <= 1k is going to be OK in all but the most demanding applications. This would mean that C is => 26.5pF

However, if your output load is only 100 ohms then R should be no greater than 1 ohm and C would be at least 26.5nF.

There are no chips that I'm aware of and even if there were it would be unlikely that they would suit your exact requirements given the loading conditions that could be encountered in your unspecified design.